# Java cannot find symbol during compiling

Tags: java, string, counter

I've got a problem. I written a program, which allows me to count to a specific number and is able to use Prefix and Suffix. I need this in order to build another program.
Here's my code (//offen is german for open, //zu for closed)

```
public class zael{ //offen1
    public static void main(String[] args){//offen2
        int z = 0;
        System.out.println("Bis welche Zahl willst du zaelen?");
        String keins = System.console().readLine();
        int k = Integer.parseInt(keins);
        System.out.println("Willst du einen prefix? (Y/N)");
        String p = System.console().readLine();
        if (p.equals ("Y")){//offen3
            System.out.println("Gib deinen Prefix an!");
            String pref = System.console().readLine();
        }//zu3
        System.out.println("Willst du einen Suffix? (Y/N)");
        String s = System.console().readLine();
        if (s.equals ("Y")) {//offen4
            System.out.println("Gib deinen Suffix an!");
            String suff = System.console().readLine();
        }//zu4
        if (p.equals ("Y")){//offen5
            while(z < k) {//offen6
                if (s.equals ("Y")) {//offen7
                    System.out.println(pref);
                    System.out.print(z+1);
                    System.out.print(suff);
                    z = z + 1;
                }//zu7
                else {//offen8
                    System.out.println(pref);
                    System.out.print(z+1);
                    z = z + 1;
                }//zu8
            }//zu6
        }//zu5
        else {//offen9
            while (z < k){//offen10
                if (s.equals ("Y")) {//offen11
                    System.out.println("Gib deinen Suffix an!");
                    String suff = System.console().readLine();
                    System.out.println(z+1 + suff);
                    z = z + 1;
                }//zu11
                else{//offen12
                    System.out.println(z+1);
                    z = z + 1;
                }//zu12
            }//zu10
        }//zu9
    }//zu2
}//zu1
```

And the errors I get are:

```
zael.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(pref);
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable pref
  location: class zael
zael.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.print(suff);
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable suff
  location: class zael
zael.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                    System.out.println(pref);
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable pref
  location: class zael
3 errors
```

Comment: Could you indent your code please? It's really a pain to read.

Comment: Count your `{` and `}`. `if(#{ != #}) error();`.

Comment: i counted them with //offen and //zu

Comment: Those //offen & //zu comments are odd. If you use a proper IDE then you don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the **scope** of your variable:

From **Java Language Specification**, [Section 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The *scope* of a declaration is the region of the program within which the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a simple name, provided it is visible.
>
> A declaration is said to be *in scope* at a particular point in a program if and only if the declaration's scope includes that point.

### So, analyzing your program...

1. The `String` variable named `pref` is declared in scope #3. Hence it can be accessed by itself and other scopes nested within it.
2. When you try to access the `pref` variable in scope #4 in lines 22 and 28.
3. The same goes for the variable `suff`.

### Now, How To Fix It?

Declare (and initialize) the variables *outside* the scopes where you need them. For example, you need the `pref` variable in scope #4. Therefore, declare it in the `main()` method, i.e. scope #2.

Then modify your  `if (p.equals ("Y")){...` statement as:

```
if (s.equals ("Y")) {//offen4
    System.out.println("Gib deinen Suffix an!");
    suff = System.console().readLine();
} else {
    // some backup mechanism like System.exit(0);
    // so that it doesn't pose a problem later.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:
`System.out.println(pref);`

You have not defined `pref` in this scope. The field `pref` is only defined in main method but cannot be read outside of it and therefore outside your main method the `pref` field has to be defined as well. *(You may define it as static member field as well to reduce code duplication.)*

Comment: But if i define it outside of the "if" it will be asked everytime and not only when the users says Y

Comment: @Taxcamp You have to define the variable in a scope which is visible, there is nothing forcing you to ask the user what it should be.

Comment: You want to define a default (fallback value for either pref and suff. They both are empty strings and visible all over your class. Then you ask the user iff he likes having prefix/suffix and in case of 'Ja, bitte' you overwrite these blank field for pref/suff in either case. That way your use case stays the same and your code compiles. Now there is the problem: if you define fields in an if-scope the field is maintained until the ent of exact this if scope and discarded there (where there is the comment '//zuX'). But you want pref/suff being visible allover your class.

Comment: You do not have to assign it outside the if block. You can simply define it outside so that the variable's scope becomes larger.

Comment: ... not outside ... but outside? ... scope larger... I don't get it. I think our ideas are the same.

Comment: @DanielSchulz - the point he is making is that you don't have to >>assign<< outside the if block.  You can define it outside then assign to it inside.  However, he has (maybe) forgotten about the definite assignment rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code it is easy to see:

```
    if (p.equals("Y")) {//offen3
        System.out.println("Gib deinen Prefix an!");
        String pref = System.console().readLine();
    }//zu3
```

In the code block above the variable pref becomes useless as its range ends once the block closes.

```
    if (s.equals("Y")) {//offen4
        System.out.println("Gib deinen Suffix an!");
        String suff = System.console().readLine();
    }//zu4
```

This is the same for the variable suff above.

Hence you get errors in the lines below:

```
System.out.println(pref);
System.out.print(z + 1);
System.out.print(suff);
```

The easiest way to fix this would be to define both variables outside the if block as follows:

```
String pref = null;
if (p.equals("Y")) {//offen3
    System.out.println("Gib deinen Prefix an!");
    pref = System.console().readLine();
}//zu3
```